# Looking to download a series of files from a remote server, asynchronously, with callbacks

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Basically, there is a script on my local network that generates a file.  I want to be able to make multiple calls to this script at the same time with different variables and present notification to the user when each particular file is ready.  I've tried doing it in Javascript, jQuery and PHP, but not having much luck.

I can't seem to get it to work asynchronously through PHP with a callback, and I can't seem to get it to actually download through Javascript or jQuery.

I've tried `$.get('script_url')` and `$('#someelement').load('script_url')` for jQuery.

I've also tried using http://github.com/coolaj86/jquery-cors and referencing http://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control to no avail.

Comment: Please share your code what you got so far.

Comment: I've tried $.get('script_url') and $('#someelement').load('script_url') for jQuery.  I've also tried using https://github.com/coolaj86/jquery-cors and referencing https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control to no avail.

Comment: Does `script_url` provide a link to the url? What happens when you do `$('#someelement').load('script_url')`? Have you checked if any response is given etc.?

Comment: Browsers probably have some limitation on number of parallel downloads.

Comment: @Niklas It would return 200 OK, but response was empty.  I figured this was probably due to CORS, since the script is on a different domain.  But I'm hoping that since it simply returns a file, there's some way I can make this work.

Comment: @Andrew If it is under a different domain/protocol, it won't work unless you use JSONP, which in your case, shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: @Niklas Not sure if JSONP is supported on that particular site.  I've also tried using cURL, but I keep getting back empty responses.  Quite frustrating =/

Comment: I think Niklas is asking for something a little more SSCCE'ish http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When script_url is a javascript var, this must work:

```
$.get(script_url, function(data){ alert 'callback' + data});
```

The function ist your callback.